# iCheck - Check the box by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

I have iCheck checkbox right next to a SHARE link.  Ideally the user ticks the box and then clicks Share link, but, sometimes they don't. How can I tick the box when they click the Share link?

```
<div class="input-group input-group-xs"><span class="input-group-addon"> 
<div class="icheckbox_square" style="position: relative;">
<input type="checkbox" name="share-item" rel="icheck" class="chk-share" style="margin: 0px; position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;" value="9954">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
</div> </span>
<span class="input-group-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs sharelink" data-toggle="modal" data-href="/modal">Share</a></span></div>
```

Also, these are in repeater, there about 50 duplicate checkbox segments, same as I posted above, on the page, so not 1 to 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure JavaScript for this by just adding a click listener to your button that runs a function that will check the input box like this:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(".sharelink");
const checkbox = document.querySelector(".chk-share");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  checkbox.checked = true;
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="share-item" rel="icheck" class="chk-share" value="9954">
<span class="input-group-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs sharelink" data-toggle="modal" data-href="/modal">Share</a></span>
```

With jQuery, the above JavaScript would look like this:

```js
$('.sharelink').click(function() {
  $('.chk-share').prop("checked", true);
})
```

---

### Multiple instances of checkbox+share:

Just wrapped all your checkbox + anchor tag pair within a common parent element like say, a `<div>` element and now you can just add a click listener to each anchor which in turn runs a function that uses the [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method to get the common parent element from which you can retrieve and edit the checkbox within it.

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".sharelink");

btns.forEach(btn=> {
 btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
   const checkbox = btn.closest('div').querySelector(".chk-share");
   checkbox.checked = true;
 });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="share-item" rel="icheck" class="chk-share" value="9954"><span class="input-group-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs sharelink" data-toggle="modal" data-href="/modal">Share</a></span>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="share-item" rel="icheck" class="chk-share" value="9954"><span class="input-group-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs sharelink" data-toggle="modal" data-href="/modal">Share</a></span>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="share-item" rel="icheck" class="chk-share" value="9954"><span class="input-group-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs sharelink" data-toggle="modal" data-href="/modal">Share</a></span>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="share-item" rel="icheck" class="chk-share" value="9954"><span class="input-group-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs sharelink" data-toggle="modal" data-href="/modal">Share</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Afraid it's not 1 to 1 relationship.  sharelink and chk-share are repeated many times

Comment: @devnuts I don't understand what you mean by 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: Meaning, there are many .sharelink and .chk-share objects on the page

Comment: @devnuts Check the second snippet that I have added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to listen `on("click")` event of `sharelink`.

After that, you can toggle checkbox click by using [prop( "checked", true )](http://%20https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/).

```js
$(".sharelink").on("click", function(){
    $(".chk-share").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group input-group-xs"><span class="input-group-addon"> 
<div class="icheckbox_square" style="position: relative;">
<input type="checkbox" name="share-item" rel="icheck" class="chk-share" style=" value="9954">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
</div> </span>
<span class="input-group-btn"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-xs sharelink" data-toggle="modal" data-href="/modal">Share</a></span></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @devnuts